# Facebook share button adds param array index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

I'm trying to set up a Facebook share button for my Ruby on Rails web app. The share button iframe src syntax is as follows:

> //www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=<%= url_encode(request.original_url) %>&layout=button&appId=XXXXXXX

The actual current URL this button loads on is:

> http://www.scotusmap.com/events?utf8=%E2%9C%93&period=term&terms%5B%5D=Summer+2014&terms%5B%5D=OT+2014&terms%5B%5D=Summer+2015&terms%5B%5D=OT+2015&terms%5B%5D=Summer+2016&terms%5B%5D=OT+2016&terms%5B%5D=Summer+2017&justices%5B%5D=

Note the params `terms` and `justices`, which are arrays. So far so good.

I've independently debugged `url_encode` and `request.original_url`, which both are working exactly as expected and returning the above URL.

**Here's the problem**: [when Facebook parses this URL](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.scotusmap.com%2Fevents%3Futf8%3D%25E2%259C%2593%26period%3Dterm%26terms%255B%255D%3DSummer%2B2014%26terms%255B%255D%3DOT%2B2014%26terms%255B%255D%3DSummer%2B2015%26terms%255B%255D%3DOT%2B2015%26terms%255B%255D%3DSummer%2B2016%26terms%255B%255D%3DOT%2B2016%26terms%255B%255D%3DSummer%2B2017%26justices%255B%255D%3D), it seems to add indices to the array params in the 'Fetched URL' (i.e. the URL it's actually scraping):

> http://www.scotusmap.com/events?utf8=%E2%9C%93&period=term&terms%5B0%5D=Summer+2014&terms%5B1%5D=OT+2014&terms%5B2%5D=Summer+2015&terms%5B3%5D=OT+2015&terms%5B4%5D=Summer+2016&terms%5B5%5D=OT+2016&terms%5B6%5D=Summer+2017&justices%5B0%5D

This is creating an error, so that when someone clicks on the Share button, the page that Facebook's scraper crawls is one that doesn't exist and therefore the metadata is all wrong too.

Anyone run into this issue before and come up with a workaround?

Comment: My guess would be that it has something to do with how they parse and reassemble query strings; probably due to it still basically being done in PHP … Two options: File a bug report and ask them to fix it, or add some rewriting on your end (if possible), that replaces all `terms[x]` to `terms[]` again, before your system further processes the URL.

Comment: Thanks! I'm basically going the first route. Bug report here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/675610165945608/